# How to solve the following Gaussian integral where $A$ is not symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-integral

$$\int \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+B^Tx\right)dx$$
where A is a real and positive-definite, i.e. $x^TAx>0$, but not necessarily symmetric. $B$ and $x$ are $n\times 1$ column vectors with real components.

When A is symmetric and positive definite, the result is the well known
$$\int\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^TAx+B^Tx\right)=\sqrt\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\det\left(A\right)}\exp\left(B^TA^{-1}B\right)$$
I have also found that when $A$ is real and positive definite but not necessarily symmetric, which is worked here:
(https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/13aa/494c312d57a92d72e408bc4f3503edaac8eb.pdf)
$$\int\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^TAx\right)=\sqrt\frac{(\pi)^n}{det\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^T\right)\right)}$$
I am thinking if it's possible to generalize the above result with a linear term $B^Tx$ for a non-symmetric $A$.

Comment: if you alter $A$ by adding a skew symmetric matrix, the value $x^TAx$ never changes. As a result, just subtract off the skew symmetric part and use the symmetric part of $A,$   namely the same $(A+A^T)/2$  they use.

Comment: Wait a second, $A$ being positive definite makes the integral diverge. You want it to be negative definite.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes thank you, editing the question